# CMake Documentation Guideline

Tags: cmake

Currently reading the [CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/index.html), I am wondering if there is any agreed on syntax guideline for it.
For example from the [Command Invocations](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-invocations) part:

> command_invocation  ::=  space* identifier space* '(' arguments ')'
>   identifier          ::=  < match '[ A-Za-z_ ][ A-Za-z0-9_ ] * ' >

I can roughly deduce the meaning. Anyway it would be nice to have some common guidelines ( e.g. why `::=` , is `[...]*` a UNIX Regular Expression as well as `space*`, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using [BNF (Backus-Naur form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), which is a de-facto standard for specifying programming language grammars.

Comment: Never heard of it. Interesting.